# Write link and New lines in a textarea with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I need to send an Invite mail.
Text will be:

> Hi mate,
>
> Join our tournament clicking this link: [http://link.to.registration.with.token](http://link_to_registration.cm)

First, I manage internationalization, so I get it like that:

```
'invite_template' => 'Hi Mate, \r\n Click the link :link ',


$message = trans('crud.invite_template', ['link' => '<a href="http://link.with.token">link</a>' ]);
```

And then :

```
  {!!  Form::textarea('message',nl2br(e($message)), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

But this is my problem:

1. I `\r\n` is changed to `<BR />`, so Textarea looks bad
2. Link is displayed in HTML too, not interpreted too

Is it possible to do so???

Comment: Maybe you would put your message on a view or use http://ckeditor.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

**You shall do this in 2 ways.**

**Method 1 :** Print the text content in Text Editor

**Step 1 :** Include `ckeditor.js`

```
<script src="{{ asset('/').('public/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
```

And then

**Step 2 :** Write your text

```
<textarea class="ckeditor">{{ $yourTextContent }}</textarea>
```

**Method 2 :**  Echo'ing the input

Just do

```
echo $yourContent;
```